# Best way to find the sum of a column in a multi-dimensional array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I am getting an output from an SQL query in the form of an array of tuples. The array looks like this-

```
(1, 100)
(2, 150)
(3, 200)
```

I want to find the sum of the columns seperately. Thus, I want to get the value 1+2+3= 6 for column 1, and also get the value 100+150+200= 450 for column 2.

When I use the built-in `var1=sum(arr[0])`, I get 101, which is the sum of the first **row** instead of **column**.

How do I add up the first column in the easiest manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [
...     (1, 100),
...     (2, 150),
...     (3, 200)
... ]
>>> list(zip(*lst))  # zip(*lst) groups the items that you want to sum
[(1, 2, 3), (100, 150, 200)]
>>>
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*lst)]
[6, 450]
>>>
```

Comment: Could you explain the `*` usage?

Comment: It unpacks the items in `lst` as arguments to `zip`.  In this case, doing `zip(*lst)` is short for `zip((1, 100), (2, 150), (3, 200))`